# Why does OSPF require all traffic between non-backbone areas to pass through a backbone area (area 0)?

Tags: routing, ospf

There is an explanation given to the above question on this link but I am not understanding that how it will create a loop. I would appreciate if someone can explain this with the help of diagrams of an OSPF network. http://www.networkworld.com/article/2348778/cisco-subnet/my-favorite-interview-question.html

Comment: Please do not post the same question on mutliple SE sites.

Comment: The OSPF protocol was designed that way. That's it. It is actually difficult to create a routing loop in OSPF or EIGRP as their default state (along with admin distances, etc) is to avoid this. It is doable however if you try really hard to do that.